# Bidirectional LSTM in seq2seq model

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to build a Encoder decoder bidirectional lstm model for my text summarization task. I am facing problems with input shape. Error: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=ListWrapper([InputSpec(shape=(None, 128), ndim=2), InputSpec(shape=(None, 128), ndim=2), InputSpec(shape=(None, 128), ndim=2), InputSpec(shape=(None, 128), ndim=2)]); however `cell.state_size` is [128, 128].
Could anyone help with this please?
Here is the model:

```
latent_dim = 128
embedding_size=512
# Encoder 
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_len_text,)) 
enc_emb = Embedding(x_voc_size, embedding_size,trainable=True)(encoder_inputs) 
#Preparing BiLSTM layer 1 
encoder_lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True) )
encoder_output1, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = encoder_lstm1(enc_emb)
# Decoder layer 
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_len_text,)) 
print(y_voc_size,latent_dim)
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(y_voc_size, latent_dim,trainable=True) 
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs) 
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs,decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state = decoder_lstm(dec_emb,initial_state=[forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c]) 
#Adding the dense layer
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_voc_size, activation='softmax')) 
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs) 

# Prepare the model
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs) 
model.summary()
```

Comment: it looks like your embedding text data into an lstm keras networks and generating multiple outputs.  what is your desired output?

Comment: when I analyzed predictions on temperature, I discovered temperature and relative humidity were closely correlated.  Likewise wind speed slowed down as humidity increased.

Comment: Desired output: summary of input text.  ALso the decoder need not be bidirectional. The error is regarding the input shape

Answer (score -1):

normalizing your dataset will reduce the noise

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
 grouped=df.groupby('valid')
 temperatures=grouped[['tmpf','relh']].mean()
 temperatures.plot(ax =ax)
 plt.xticks(rotation=90)
 plt.ylabel('Temperature')
 plt.xlabel('Date')
 plt.title('Idaho')

 look_back = 3

 # LSTM configuration 1
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
 model.add(Dense(1))
 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

 dataset=temperatures
 scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
 dataset = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(dataset).reshape(-1,1))


 # convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
 def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=3):
     dataX, dataY = [], []
     for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
         a = dataset[i:(i+look_back)]
         dataX.append(a)
         dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back])
     return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

 # normalize the dataset

 # split into train and test sets
 train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.80)
 test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
 train, test = dataset[0:train_size], dataset[train_size:len(dataset)]
 print(len(train), len(test))

 trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
 testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

 # reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
 trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
 testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

 model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: https://github.com/dnishimoto/python-deep-learning/blob/master/Idaho%20Weather%20in%20Sep%202020.ipynb   (In this code sample I regularize the data which normalizes the numeric data between 0 and 1 to reduce noise.  Next, I add a 3 day look back LSTM layer to the keras network. I found that relative humidity affects wind speed and temperature and relative humidity correlate

Comment: at the bottom of the notes I use LSTM to predict temperature.

Comment: I noticed in your code you use a final dense layer using softmax.  Are you creating multiple output predictions?  why do you need the bidirectional lstm?